# Integration test with TestRestTemplate for Multipart POST request returns 400

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, resttemplate

I know that similar question has been here already couple of times but following suggested fixes did not solve my problem.

I have a simple controller with the following endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    log.debug("Upload controller - POST: {}", file.getOriginalFilename());

    // do something
}
```

I am trying to write an integration test for it using Spring `TestRestTemplate` but all of my attemps end with `400 - Bad Request` (no logs clarifying what went wrong in console).

The log inside the controller did not get hit so it failed before getting there.

Could you please take a look on my test and suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
@Test
public void testUpload() {
    // simulate multipartfile upload
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("image.jpg").getFile());

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.add("file", file);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parameters, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.exchange(UPLOAD, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class, "");

    // Expect Ok
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting the ContentType = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA on the test. But your controller is not set to receive this type of request.
Try using consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}
Please post the rest of the Test class as there are some missing pieces that I couldn't reproduce here

Comment: @BrunoLeite Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it but that is not the case.

Comment: do you actually return a string with your response entity? have you verified what's at the body of your 400 response in case it provides more details? have you considered running it with a debugger or implementing an exception handler?

Comment: Yes, String is being returned. It works fine outside of the integration test. In this test I posted. I don't even get the debug line so something is happening before it gets to the body of the controller.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I tried the following:

```
@Test
public void testUpload() {
    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.add("file", new org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource("image.jpg"));

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parameters, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.exchange(UPLOAD, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class, "");

    // Expect Ok
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

As you can see I used the `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource` as object for the file and ti worked like a charm

I hope it's useful

Angelo

Comment: It is not clear to me what was causing the problem in the first place. Is the multipart controller not compatible with `java.io.File`? Anyway, it does work like a charm, thank you. This saved me a lot of work!

Comment: @Smajl I guess that the rest template is able in managing the `org.springframework.core.it.Resource` implementation better than passing a simple `java.io.File`

Comment: I know this is quite old, but can I ask you, where is your "image.jpg" file located in your project?

Comment: @bot_bot In my code the image is under the classpath (that is in `src/main/resources` if you are using maven)

Answer (score 3):

`FileSystemResource` also could be used in case if you want to use  `java.nio.file.Path`.

Package: `org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource`

For example, you could do this:

```
new FileSystemResource(Path.of("src", "test", "resources", "image.jpg"))
```

Full code example:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UploadFilesTest {

    private final TestRestTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public UploadFilesTest(TestRestTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @Test
    public void uploadFileTest() {
        var multipart = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        multipart.add("file", file());

        final ResponseEntity<String> post = template.postForEntity("/upload", new HttpEntity<>(multipart, headers()), String.class);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, post.getStatusCode());
    }

    private HttpHeaders headers() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        return headers;
    }

    private FileSystemResource file() {
        return new FileSystemResource(Path.of("src", "test", "resources", "image.jpg"));
    }
}
```

Rest controller:

```java
@RestController
public class UploadEndpoint {
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println(file.getSize());
    }
}
```